# Using iText 5.5 to Resize Large PDF Images

Tags: java, itext, large-files

I'm using iText 5.5.10 (community edition).  I'm leveraging the code from these examples: http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/image-examples/large-image-examples#45-largeimage2.java.

We're using the code to resize large engineering images (44x32) to the more palatable (11x17).  Unfortunately it errors out regularly on files > 17MB with a null pointer exception on the last line.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(Image.java:668)

PdfDictionary page = reader.getPageN(1);
PdfDictionary resources = page.getAsDict(PdfName.RESOURCES);
PdfDictionary xobjects = resources.getAsDict(PdfName.XOBJECT);
PdfName imgName = xobjects.getKeys().iterator().next();
Image img = Image.getInstance((PRIndirectReference) xobjects.getAsIndirectObject(imgName));
```

I'm not an iText or PDF expert by any stretch of the imagination, can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?  We also have ASPOSE.NET for PDF but that honestly that's been less reliable than the free version of iText.

Comment: Did you debugged it once? I mean there are 3 method invocations on the last line. So which one does fail? Maybe you should post the stack trace if it is helpful.

Comment: I've debugged it several times, I missed the line of code it errors out on but I've added it and the null pointer into the post.

Comment: `xobjects.getAsIndirectObject(imgName)` returns null. See [JavaDoc](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfDictionary.html#getAsIndirectObject-com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName-)

Comment: Ah, I see, there's only an image on one page so I assumed there would be only one key, I guess PDF is doing something more.  So I'm guessing I need to loop through the keyset and find one that's an image key...if you could point me in the right direction that'd be great, if not, then I will go doc diving.

Comment: Ok, I'm seriously stuck.  I can't figure out how to figure out which of the PdfName objects that are on my single page PDF is the image so I can cast it directly or indirectly to an object to manipulate.  Can't seem to find an example that fits the bill.  I know it's likely obvious but whatever that basic concept might be, I'm not getting it...